# How to compute a list of validators and return a Seq[String]

Tags: scala

I am creating these validators that will accumulate all the error messages.

```
trait UserValidator {
  def validate(user: User): UserValidator
  def errors: Seq[String]
}

case class UserIdExistsValidator(id: Int, xs: List[User] = Nil) extends UserValidator {
  def validate(user: User) = if(user.id == id) copy(xs = user :: xs) else this
  def errors = if(xs.isEmpty) Seq[s"User with id $id was not found"] else Seq.empty
}
```

Now what I want to do is, say I have a bunch of these types of Validator classes like `UserIdExistsValidator`.

How would I go through all of them given this:

```
val users: List[User] = loadUsers()
val validators: List[UserValidator] = loadValidators()
```

How can I loop through each validator and pass in all the users, so that at the end of the computation I have a Seq[String] error messages for all the errors.

Answer (score 3):

```
validators.flatMap(v => users.map(v.validate)).flatMap(_.errors)
```

or:

```
val combinations = for {
   v <- validators
   u <- users
} yield v.validate(u)

combinations.flatMap(_.errors)
```

Both expressions return a `List[String]`

**EDIT**:
Per clarification of question - now using `foldLeft` to get each validator run through all users (potentially collecting errors for these users), then collecting all the errors from all these "final" validators using `flatMap`:

```
validators.flatMap(v =>
  // folding left, starting with original validator, "aggregating" errors: 
  users.foldLeft(v) { case (v1, u) => v1.validate(u) }.errors
)
```

Comment: But it has to run .validate on all the users, then at the end call .errors.

Comment: Not sure what the difference is (if each validator is independent of the others) - but updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: The difference is that it will return multiple errors for each failed user, instead of a single error for the entire list of users. make sense?

Comment: Oh, that requirement is very unclear in the question. So - each user should be validated by each validator _until the first failure_ or until all validators pass?

Comment: Each validator will run through all the users.  Once they have run through all the users, then you can call errors.  Right now it seems it is returning multiple errors for a list of users, instead of just 1 error.  I'll create a scastie.

Comment: I think I understood your intention now, although for the given example validator I still think the result would be the same. Either way - see updated answer. Hope it helps.